# How does one make two characters active?

Tags: fonts, characters, ligatures

In russian babel, it's possible to write `<<` to get a russian opening quote character. However, some fonts that have such character (like the one provided by anttor package) don't use that and end up with ugly output like << this is my quote>>. I tried making `<` active and saying something  like

```
%\def << {\guillemotleft}%
```

but making `<` active messes the occasions where it is used not as a part of `<<`. I tried to search where `<<` is defined in babel, but couldn't find it. So, is there an elegant way to make a *sequence* if characters active, s that one can `\def` them? Or, perhaps, there is a much more elegant solution to my problem of which I don't know...

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that `<<` is defined as a ligature in those fonts, similarly as `fi` (to produce one glyph) or dashes `--` and `---`.

```
\makeatletter
% store `<` with the original catcode
\let\old@lt<
\let\old@gt>
% make `<` active
\catcode`\<\active
\catcode`\>\active
% test for 2nd `<` and if present, print quotation marks and gobble the 2nd `<`
\def<{\@ifnextchar<{\guillemotleft\@gobble}\old@lt}
\def>{\@ifnextchar>{\guillemotright\@gobble}\old@gt}
\makeatother
```

This is 100% surely breaking in `beamer` and probably corrupting the `<` and `>` table column specifications.