# How to add a global structure specified hyphenation rule?

Tags: hyphenation

I have written a document with 200 references. (every round bracket (...) in my document is a collocation (here a combination of three words) which shouldn't get split. What I want is to have the structure: "(i j)" on only one line.

One possible solution to solve this problem is to use a global definition and then to use each time the link to this macro:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,top=2cm,bottom=4cm,bindingoffset=5mm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\nobreakword}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}

"Und wir haben die Liebe erkannt und geglaubt, die Gott zu uns hat. Gott ist Liebe, und wer in der Liebe bleibt, der bleibt in Gott und Gott in ihm" \nobreakword{(1. Johannes 4,16)}

"Der HERR ist mir erschienen von ferne: Ich habe dich je und je geliebt, darum habe ich dich zu mir gezogen aus lauter Güte." \nobreakword{(Jeremia 31,3)}

"Denn so hat Gott die Welt geliebt, dass er seinen eingeborenen Sohn gab, damit jeder, der an ihn glaubt, nicht verloren geht, sondern ewiges Leben hat.'' \nobreakword{(Joh. 3,16)}

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

The sentence structure inside the round brackets should not be broken without declaring with \nobreakword{(...)} because this takes a lot of time. LaTex should recognize manually the collocation because of the round brackets (...) and dont split it.

I guess LaTex is not able to read pattern starting with "(" and ending with ")" and automatically recognize that this symbols (without writing a "\" command directly in the text) declares that the text including the round brackets have to be on the same line. Or is it possible?

Comment: Assuming you don't actually have underscores in the word(s) (not that it really matters), this should be as simple as `\newcommand{\nobreakword}{\mbox}` which makes `\nobreakword` act exactly like `\mbox`; or `\newcommand{\nobreakword}[1]{\mbox{(#1)}}` (which includes the brackets `(..)`). Then you'd use `\nobreakword{...}`. However, you may run into problems where `(...different_text_inside_the_brackets...)` run into the margin. For this `\sloppy` could help.

Comment: @Werner I think the first is needed, isn't it? So that you can say `\nobreakword{"text" (whatever inside the brackets)}`? Though I'm not sure I've understood 'combination' correctly....

Comment: @Werner I've tried \newcommand{\nobreakword}{\mbox} \newcommand{\nobreakword}[1]{\mbox{(#1)}} \nobreakword{...} without luck. Actually the reference in the round brackets contains many different words which are separate with normal blank characters, but the whole reference including the round brackets can be placed on only one line.

Comment: It would help if you posted your attempt at `\nobreakword`.  An `\mbox` will not break across lines, but it could wind up sticking out in odd or less desirable ways if its content is rather long.

Comment: ...after you defined the macro, you need to use it. So you'll need `...sehr langer Text. \nobreakword{(Erster ...)} Dies ist ein...`

Comment: So I really have to write this \nobreakword{.......} 200 times? (I've 200 such collocations in my text.)

Comment: @laminin: Let me stop you right there and make the following request: Please update your post so that we have something to work with rather than supplying minimal non-useful examples. If you have a specific way or writing the `(...)` references in your text, one could tap into that mechanism and make it write itself inside a `\nobreakword` macro... If you go out and buy peanut butter... the sandwich doesn't go and make itself now does it...?

Comment: ...what I'm trying to say is that you should show us your use-case as well. It doesn't have to include the 200+ collections, just one, so we can see what your way of writing them are. Make sure that you supply us with a minimal example that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and replicate your current setup.

Comment: Actually there are quotes: There is no logic inside the brackets.

"Und wir haben die Liebe erkannt und geglaubt, die Gott zu uns hat. Gott ist Liebe, und wer in der Liebe bleibt, der bleibt in Gott und Gott in ihm" (1. Johannes 4,16)

"Der HERR ist mir erschienen von ferne: Ich habe dich je und je geliebt, darum habe ich dich zu mir gezogen aus lauter Güte." (Jeremia 31,3)

"Denn so hat Gott die Welt geliebt, dass er seinen eingeborenen Sohn gab, damit jeder, der an ihn glaubt, nicht verloren geht, sondern ewiges Leben hat." (Johannes 3,16)

Comment: @laminin: Are they the _only_ thing between brackets? No nesting.. no, oh yes, there are other non-phrase referenced-brackets somewhere... no brackets, period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have the references inside brackets and nothing else fancy... not even nested, then you can make `(` active and capture the contents between `(...)` to manage it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\nobreakword}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\begin{document}

\raggedright

BEFORE\ldots

``Und wir haben die Liebe erkannt und geglaubt, die Gott zu uns hat. Gott ist Liebe, und wer in der Liebe bleibt, der bleibt in Gott und Gott in ihm'' (1.\ Johannes 4,16)

``Der HERR ist mir erschienen von ferne: Ich habe dich je und je geliebt, darum habe ich dich zu mir gezogen aus lauter Güte.'' (Jeremia 31,3)

``Denn so hat Gott die Welt geliebt, dass er seinen eingeborenen Sohn gab, damit jeder, der an ihn glaubt, nicht verloren geht, sondern ewiges Leben hat.'' (Joh.\ 3,16)

\let\oldlbrack( % Store old meaning of "("
\catcode`\(\active % Make "(" active
\def(#1){\nobreakword{\oldlbrack{}#1)}} % Define "(" to capture everything between (..) and ...
                                        % ... wrap it inside a \nobreakword.

AFTER\ldots

``Und wir haben die Liebe erkannt und geglaubt, die Gott zu uns hat. Gott ist Liebe, und wer in der Liebe bleibt, der bleibt in Gott und Gott in ihm'' (1.\ Johannes 4,16)

``Der HERR ist mir erschienen von ferne: Ich habe dich je und je geliebt, darum habe ich dich zu mir gezogen aus lauter Güte.'' (Jeremia 31,3)

``Denn so hat Gott die Welt geliebt, dass er seinen eingeborenen Sohn gab, damit jeder, der an ihn glaubt, nicht verloren geht, sondern ewiges Leben hat.'' (Joh.\ 3,16)

\end{document}
```

Here is a very short introduction to the above procedure: [How does one make two characters active?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96429/5764)

---

For future reference, if you have something that is really repetitive, consider wrapping it in a macro. It allows you to tap into that macro in the future and manipulate its contents rather than resorting to `\catcode` trickery.

Comment: You made my day! In the text I found two examples 1.) a very long sentence inside a round bracket which is too long for one line and 2.) a structure containing a URL: (nach Hebr 4,12; http://www.bibleserver.com/text/SLT/Hebr%C3%A4er4.12-15) Can I also manually say that these two cases are excluded from being active?

Comment: If you want to exclude certain ones from the now-active `(` mechanism, you can use `\oldlbrack ... )` in your text rather than `( ... )`. `\oldlbrack` is a capture of `(` before it was made active and changed.

Answer (score 1):

If your reference is always going to be preceded by quoted material, you could do something along the following lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myquote{\my@quote}
\def\my@quote(#1)#2{``#2''~\mbox{(#1)}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\myquote(1. Johannes 4,16){Und wir haben die Liebe erkannt und geglaubt, die Gott zu uns hat. Gott ist Liebe, und wer in der Liebe bleibt, der bleibt in Gott und Gott in ihm} 

\end{document}
```

It's not necessary to put the source first, I could have defined this as

```
\def\my@quote#1(#2){``#1''~\mbox{(#2)}}
```

The `~` is in there so that the reference isn't isolated on a line by itself.